# What is the difference between Java vararg with direct type vs wildcard generic via extends?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

How do following 2 Java method declarations differ:

```
public <S extends Item> void withExtra1(S... extra) {
    Collections.addAll(pool, extra);
}
```

and:

```
public void withExtra2(Item... extra) {
    Collections.addAll(pool, extra);
}
```

Comment: They technically have a different method signature (as they differ in the number of type variables); so you couldn't use one to override the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java spec says

> A Java compiler must output generic signature information for any class, interface, constructor or member whose generic signature in the Java programming language would include references to type variables or parameterized types.

If you check the bytecode you can see the method with generics has a different signature:

```
  public <S extends Item> void withExtra1(S...);
    descriptor: ([LItem;)V
    flags: (0x0081) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #2                  // Field pool:Ljava/util/List;
         4: aload_1
         5: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/util/Collections.addAll:(Ljava/util/Collection;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
         8: pop
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
        line 10: 9
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0  this   LItem;
            0      10     1 extra   [LItem;
      LocalVariableTypeTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     1 extra   [TS;
    Signature: #23                          // <S:LItem;>([TS;)V


  public void withExtra2(Item...);
    descriptor: ([LItem;)V
    flags: (0x0081) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: getfield      #2                  // Field pool:Ljava/util/List;
         4: aload_1
         5: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/util/Collections.addAll:(Ljava/util/Collection;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
         8: pop
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 13: 0
        line 14: 9
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      10     0  this   LItem;
            0      10     1 extra   [LItem;
```

`#23` in the constant pool is `#23 = Utf8               <S:LItem;>([TS;)V`

You can access this information at runtime using reflection:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Item {

    List<Item> pool;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (var m : Item.class.getMethods())
            System.out.println(m.getName() + " " +
                    Arrays.toString(m.getGenericParameterTypes()));
    }


    public <S extends Item> void withExtra1(S... extra) {
        Collections.addAll(pool, extra);
    }

    public void withExtra2(Item... extra) {
        Collections.addAll(pool, extra);
    }

}
```

stdout:

```
main [class [Ljava.lang.String;]
withExtra1 [S[]]
withExtra2 [class [LItem;]
wait [long]
wait [long, int]
wait []
equals [class java.lang.Object]
toString []
hashCode []
getClass []
notify []
notifyAll []
```

Answer (score 4):

They don't, since `S` will be erased to `Item`, both signatures end up as `Item...`.

Comment: A corrollary is that I've personally found that whenever you have a generic method with a single argument like this (or a zero-argument method with only a return type) it's more clear to not use generics and just use the upper bound as the type, with no loss of funtionality.

Comment: @markspace not just a single argument: this is also why JUnit had `assertEquals(Object, Object)`, rather than `assertEquals(T,T)`.

Comment: That's a point.  A single parameterized type might be a better way of expressing it, although when that single type includes an method argument and a return type I think the rule breaks down.  Eh, "think before coding" works too.  @AndyTurner

Answer (score 1):

The two signatures are equivalent, assuming the caller does not provide an explicit type witness. Any set of arguments that can be accepted by one signature is accepted by the other:

- Any set of arguments that is accepted by the first signature, must consist of expressions that have type equal to or a subtype of `S`, and since `S` is equal to or a subtype of `Item`, all the expressions have type equal to or a subtype of `Item`, and is accepted by the second signature.
- Any set of arguments that is accepted by the second signature, must consist of expressions that have type equal to or a subtype of `Item`, and can be passed to the first signature if `S` is inferred to be `Item` (which it can, since `Item` is within `S`'s bound of `extends Item`)